# How to use Xvfb in Ubuntu 14.04 with/without RandR?

Tags: 14.04, firefox, xvfb, randr

I try to run Unit-Tests with Selenium running Firefox on my Ubuntu 14.04 Server. And I'm using Xvfb as described [in this blog](http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/) to simulate a virtual display to show Firefox in.

But Xvfg somehow doesn't load/work with RandR. Because whenever I try this:

```
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac &
export DISPLAY=:10
firefox
```

I get an `Xlib:  extension "RandR" missing on display ":10"`-Error.

I've also tried `sudo Xvfb :10 -ac +extension RANDR`, `sudo Xvfb :10 -ac -extension RANDR` and beacuse it supplies with "xrandr" also `apt-get install x11-xserver-utils`.

And my setup is a plain empty Ubuntu 14.04 Server with `apt-get install xvfb firefox`.

Can anyone please help me run Xvfb with or without RandR?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After hours of struggling the error is still there.
But finally I've figured out, that it's more like a warning and that Firefox actually starts. Moreover, my Selenium-Tests are running.

The actual problem was, I used an old Selenium Version and the newest Firefox. And they didn't work well together.

Comment: What version of selenium and firefox have you used?